# Efficient way to convert a lot of dates - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, optimization

I'm trying to prepare importer for my application.
I've a file, very simple but large .txt. It has ~250k rows, in each row I need to change few column's date format to 'Y-m-d'.

I used `strtotime()` and `date()`, but there was some problems with that and I start to use class `DateTime`, now everything is fine, but it takes a lot time to import it (a lot of more than when I use `strtotime` and `date`).

```
//script do it every row
$date= new DateTime($values[1]);
$values[1]=$date->format('Y-m-d');
$date= new DateTime($values[2]);
$values[2]=$date->format('Y-m-d');
```

In `$values[]` I have string e.g. `Jul  1 2004 12:00AM`

There is the more efficient way to use this `DateTime` class? Something like define `$date` once and then just change values of it? I google it and tried to do in many ways using `DateTime`, but found nothing interested.

I'm still try to find out what's wrong was with `strtotime()`, in some case it don't get right date and put into mysql table -> `1969-12-31`. Main problem is I get this file from outside provider and it's run every day by cron.

It appears some of dates in file are in very strange format : `2013-01-30 15:04:30.717000000`, after clean this, it start work fine and I can use strtotime which is of course faster than DateTime.

Comment: You could always loop through `$values` rather than write out each line.

Comment: If you pre-emptively know what the format will be then [date_create_from_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php) may be a bit quicker.

Comment: _“I used strtotime() and date(), but there was some problems with that”_ – and those where what exactly? strtotime doesn’t have problems parsing a date format like your example `Jul 1 2004 12:00AM`

Comment: DateTime is by nature around 50% slower. Maybe you should try to fix the strtotime issues? whatever they were.

Comment: FYI, `strtotime()` basically uses the same parser than `DateTime()` and `date()` basically uses the same format codes than `format()`. Whatever issues you had, they should remain.

Comment: I've written a quick and dirty script and (using your own code) it can store and parse 1 million dates in aprox. 7 seconds in my PC (which is not particularly high-end). How long does it take in your server?

Comment: if it is comma seperated csv file , you can transfer it to some temporary mysql table using loaddata and the you can convert into desired  format.

Comment: Neither `strtotime()` not `Date()` accept `'2013-01-30 15:04:30.717000000'`. The only difference is that `Date()` reports it.

Comment: I predict that the bulk of the time is in reading the lines, not in parsing dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
select unix_timestamp('2013-01-30 15:04:30.717000000');
```

-->

```
1359587070.717000
```

and

```
select cast('2013-01-30 15:04:30.717000000' AS DATETIME(6));
```

-->

```
2013-01-30 15:04:30.717000
```

That is, if this is destined to be in a MySQL database, you could store it as a string, then use the above code to convert to a `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` with microsecond precision.